# Transfering mysql data from wamp enviroment to centOS

Tags: mysql, sql-server, linux, centos

I have copy of `.sql` file that contains large data. I saved it from phpmyadmin while I was using WAMP for development. Now I am working with CentOS, and I have transferred the data to my VirtualBox running CentOs already.

So, the problem is not about transferring the file but running the `.sql` file using shell, so the data can be transferred to the new mysql server.

Does anyone know any commands?

Initially I thought moving this entire directory:

```
C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\data
```

To my new server environment would be a good idea, but I can't seem to find where the `data` folder is kepyt in centos-mysql.

`whereis mysql` gives `mysql: /usr/bin/mysql /usr/lib/mysql /usr/share/mysql /usr/share/man/man1/mysql.1.gz`

I have checked all this folders to find the **data** folder but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you created the `.sql` file with mysqldump or if it is otherwise a legal mysql script containing sql commands you can simply pipe this contents to your centOs mysql instance:

```
$ mysql -uroot -p dbname < dump.sql
```

where dbname is the name of your database and dump.sql your `.sql` file.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

```
1- In your Windows Environment, from command line(CMD), go to the folder:
   cd "C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin
2- Run: mysqldump -uroot -pYourPassword DataBaseName > myBackup.sql
3- On your centOs machine, open a terminal:
   mysql -uroot -p
4- In mysql console:
   create database DataBaseName;
   exit;
5- Transfer the myBackup from your Windows System, to centOS, open a terminal in 
   the same directory where myBackup.sql lives:
   mysql -uroot -p DataBaseName < myBackup.sql
```